# addEventListener for keydown on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a canvas app that responds to keyboard and mouse input. I have this code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    alert('mousedown');
        }, false);
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    alert('keydown');
        }, false);
```

The 'mousedown' alert comes up whenever I click the mouse, but the 'keydown' alert never comes up. The same code works fine on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/uteha3/66/

Why isn't it working on my page? Does canvas not recognize keyboard input?

Comment: `keydown` is probably only fired on the canvas if it has focus. I'm not sure if a canvas element can have focus at all.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Edit** - This answer *is* a solution, but a much simpler and proper approach would be setting the `tabindex` attribute on the canvas element (as suggested by hobberwickey).

<s>You can't focus a canvas element. A simple work around this, would be to make your "own" focus.</s>

```
var lastDownTarget, canvas;
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        lastDownTarget = event.target;
        alert('mousedown');
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if(lastDownTarget == canvas) {
            alert('keydown');
        }
    }, false);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AustinBrunkhorst/qsULv/)**

Comment: old answer, but even in 2012 you absolutely could: you need to give the canvas a `tabindex="<some number>"` and presto: your canvas (but really *any* HTML element) now works fine with focus. This answer should not be flagged as correct, with hobberwickey's answer accepted instead.

Comment: I agree with you, but for whatever reason @Cbas never accepted hobberwickeys answer. I've updated my post for future visitors to address this.

Answer (score 129):

Set the tabindex of the canvas element to 1 or something like this

```
<canvas tabindex='1'></canvas>
```

It's an old trick to make any element focusable

Comment: This is the only way how I could assign a keypress event listener to the HTML5 canvas. I am doing Easeljs stage stuff. This did not work: `$('canvas').keypress( function(e) { ... }` until I added the tabindex in HTML. Thanks a lot. Only drawback for easeljs, mouseover events lose focus (e.g. shadows for stage elements when mouseover).

Comment: this worked for me but i am noticing that setting the tabindex to 1 bogs performance of canvas in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

encapsulate all of your js code within a window.onload function. I had a similar issue. Everything is loaded asynchronously in javascript so some parts load quicker than others, including your browser. Putting all of your code inside the onload function will ensure everything your code will need from the browser will be ready to use before attempting to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just setting canvas's tabindex to '1' (or '0') works. But sometimes - it doesn't, for some strange reason.

In my case (ReactJS app, dynamic canvas el creation and mount) I need to call canvasEl.focus() to fix it.
Maybe this is somehow related to React (my old app based on KnockoutJS works without '..focus()' )