# addEventListener keydown not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I took some basic Pong code available on the internet and tried to add keypresses, the code is here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ping-pong-game-tutorial-with-html5-canvas-and-sounds

I added this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("keydown", handlekeydown, true);
```

After this existing code:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackPosition, true);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", btnClick, true);
```

And I also added this:

```
function handlekeydown(e) {
  console.log("debug");
  console.log("keycode: "+e.keyCode);
}
```

But the function is never called even though I try pressing various keys. Why is this? I'm pretty sure the Canvas is in focus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [addEventListener for keydown on Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't assign the `keydown` event to the canvas because you can't focus the canvas with the cursor. You will need to assign the event to the window:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", handle, true);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try to replace *canvas* with **window**.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first floor, but you can try to do this. As follows:

```
//set attribute tabindex = 0 (other number), ensure the canvas in the focus sequence
//like this, you can focus canvas
//http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp
<canvas id="snake" width="400" height="600" tabindex=0 > </canvas> 

//then register keydown event
document.getElementById("snake").addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
          console.log(ev);
}, true);
```