# How to move one object on canvas (PACMAN) when press a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, addeventlistener, pacman

I have a problem with my Javascript program. I'm doing pacman. I need to move the image ( pacman ) on canvas When the user press a key , so I made a function that was run when the event occurs . I think the problem is produced because event is not taken. I need your help. Thanks!!

```
function startGame()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    pacman_derecha.src = 'pacman_derecha.jpg';
    pacman_derecha.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(pacman_derecha, pos_pacman_x,pos_pacman_y);
    }

    /* Procedimiento principal */

    /* Dibujamos el escenario */
    for (var i = 0; i < escenario.length; i++)
    {
        var x = escenario[i].x;
        var y = escenario[i].y;
        var ancho = escenario[i].ancho;
        var alto = escenario[i].alto;
        context.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeRect(x, y, ancho, alto);
    }

    /* Dibujamos las bolitas */
    context.strokeStyle = "#f3f3f3";
    for(var j = 0; j < bolas.length; j++)
    {
        var x = bolas[j].x;
        var y = bolas[j].y;
        context.strokeRect(x,y,2,2);
    }

    /* Pintamos de nuevo el escenario y la nueva posicion del pacman */
    setInterval(drawloop, 10);

    /* Analizamos si el usuario presiona alguna tecla */
    canvas.addEventListener('keydown', movimiento, true);

}

function movimiento(evento)
{
    alert(evento.keyCode);
    switch (evento.keyCode)
    {
        /*derecha*/
        case 39:
            pos_pacman_x = pos_pacman_x + 200;
            break;

        /*izquierda*/
        case 37:
            pos_pacman_x = pos_pacman_x - 200;
            break;

        /*abajo*/
        case 40:
            pos_pacman_y = pos_pacman_y - 200;
            break;

        /*arriba*/
        case 38:
            pos_pacman_y = pos_pacman_y + 200;
            break;

        default:
            pos_pacman_x = pos_pacman_x + 50;
            pos_pacman_y = pos_pacman_y - 50;
            break;
    }
}

function drawloop()
{
    pacman_arriba.src = 'pacman_arriba.jpg';
    pacman_arriba.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(pacman_arriba, pos_pacman_x,pos_pacman_y);
    }
    alert(pos_pacman_x+" - "+pos_pacman_y)
}
```

Comment: When you change your values, do you modify the image location ?

Comment: please paste your code here instead of using a screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647810/addeventlistener-keydown-not-working

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make a `canvas` listen for `keydown`-events, because you cannot focus it with your cursor. You have to make the window listen for these events instead:

```
window.onkeydown = movimiento;
```

Comment: I have published the code. I was reading about this, but i think that it's not the problem because canvas is the name of one var and this var has got the element canvas.

Comment: I know that `canvas` is just a variable and points to the actual canvas in your HTML code (like your code says, by using `document.getElementById(...)`. But this does not change anything about a canvas not being focusable, thus you cannot add a working `keydown` event listener to it.

Comment: Ok, I have just changed the code, but it's not working. Can I ejecute the same code of my last function 'movimiento' or I have to change any sentence?

Comment: I think you don't have to change anything in `movimiento`, because the event's contents should stay the same, no matter wheather `window` or someone else forwards the event to `movimiento`.

Comment: It's not working... Thanks for your help. :*

Comment: What is not working exacty? The entire keydown-checking-function? If it's just a syntax error, take a look at the built-in web console. In Firefox, you can find it under Extras->Web developer->Web console. It should log all syntax errors in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Ooh! Thanks, I don't know this. I've used this trick and the console has shown me this message: 'Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined'

Comment: @Wilt I know what is a console, but i dind't know where it is. Even so, this page is for ask and response question, or not? So, I think that your comment is unnecessary.

Comment: Actually you *can* have html5 canvas listen for key events. You just have to set its tabstop and then listen for keyevents. Just like an input-type-text, the user must click inside the canvas to get its focus. Therefore, it's probably easier to listen for keyevents on the document and then respond only if the issuing element is your canvas.