# Difference between key listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, keylistener

I been reading articles about game development in HTML5 canvas but none of them are usually optimized. While reading multiple articles I have found different methods of have key listeners in javascript.
First one I found

```
window.addEventListener(
"keydown",
eventReaction,
false
);
```

Second one I found

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
//do stuff with this
};
```

What are the differences between them? Which one is the proper one to use or fastest? I do not want to use a deprecated method, I just want to use the one that is proper for html5 canvas... If this is a bad question please do not -rep me, just tell me and I'll remove it.

Comment: The latter is old stuff. `addEventListener` is the way to go nowadays.

Comment: I just realized that `canvas.addEventListener( "keydown", function r(e){alert(e.keyCode);}, true);` doesnt work for me I wonder why....

Comment: I think because of element focus. If you change it in `window.addEventListener` it will work.

Comment: But wouldnt that add listener to the whole window, and events would be used when the user is away from the canvas?

Comment: I see.. you can't focus the canvas element. [solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas)

Comment: But then I get events when I click outside of the canvas, thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second piece of code you specify a listener directly on the HTMLElement.
This is not deprecated but it's not the way to go.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
//do stuff with this
};
```

The first piece you specify a listener for an HTMLElement. This way you can specify multiple events for an action.
This is definitely the way to go.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",eventReaction,false);
```

*Note: `addEventListener` is supported for modern browsers and IE>8*

PS: Bad questions don't exist, only bad answers ;)

Comment: I really did wish that I could add the eventlistener to only the canvas... I found out that `canvas.onkeypress` works and only when the user is using the canvas, but its not the way to go.... Thanks and there are bad questions thats why I had to make a new account since my old account got to much -rep and got banned

Comment: Most people are judging questions on the [general rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If your question is too broad or off-topic you will get downvoted quickly.