# How do I capture a keydown event on the canvas without interfering with the rest of my website?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, addeventlistener

I am working on a canvas game using a few tutorials and tweaking them for some AI interaction. The game works great except my event listeners are just added to the document at the moment. When I moved the game to my actual website this became an issue because I needed to `e.preventDefault` to keep the page from scrolling around. Not a big deal until people wanted to type into my contact form and they couldn't use the space bar or arrow keys. Simple enough fix seems to be adding the event listener only to my canvas.

However, when I use `canvas.addEventListener()` with the same parameters that I was using it before I can't make the canvas pay attention to the events. They don't seem to register at all. I've tried clicking on the canvas to get it "focussed" but that doesn't seem to do anything.

So the question is how can I make the canvas and only the canvas listen to keydown events?

**This works but breaks my forms**

```
addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40:
        case 32: e.preventDefault(); break;
        default: break;
    }
}, false);
```

**This doesn't work**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('world');
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40:
        case 32: e.preventDefault(); break;
        default: break;
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample code of event registering?

Comment: Let me know if you need more information? I think I handled what you were asking? The keysDown array gets handled in my main game loop and there's more code on case 32 to start the game. I have put a console.log in the event listener function which doesn't print when I have canvas.add instead of just add

Comment: Where do you declare `keysDown[e.keyCode]` array?

Comment: Above that by a couple lines. Simply an empty array. On keyup I delete that keycode. That isn't part of the issue since a console.log before that code doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this other question:
[addEventListener for keydown on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas)

The fix was by caching the last focused element, and then asking if it's the canvas, then do something different.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

The way I handle it [in my game engine](https://github.com/MCluck90/psykick2d/blob/master/src/input.js#L51) is I place my canvas inside of a `div` then capture the events from there. Make certain you set the `tabindex` on the `div` so that it can be focused.

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.rect(0, 0, 320, 240);
ctx.fillStyle = '#0F0';
ctx.fill();
var container = document.querySelector('div');
container.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```css
div:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="1">
  <canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it will probably work and it's a well formatted answer but Juan Pablo's answer hit me first and it worked for me so I'm accepting his.

Answer (score 0):

Important part is to set tabIndex of canvas to 1 ( which is dirty trick to make any element focusable ).

```
const canvasDiv = document.getElementById('my_canvas')
canvasDiv.childNodes[0].tabIndex = '1'
```

Now you can:

```
canvasDiv.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e,keyCode)
}, false)
```

Please note that Im using **keyup** - cause it captures also Del, Home, End, Ins... buttons, **keydown** captures only Ins from those. **keypress** is meant to capture only printable keys. So chose whatever suits your needs.

Comment: This seems to work, but does require the canvas have focus before it will fire any keyboard events. Not really unexpected, but I thought it should be pointed out.