# How to draw circle centered at mouse location when a key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change this jQuery code slightly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#canvas').attr('height', $('#canvas').css('height'));
$('#canvas').attr('width', $('#canvas').css('width'));
     $("#special").click(function(e){ 

        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

        /* var c=document.getElementById("special"); */
        var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); /*c.getContext("2d");*/
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 50,0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

        $('#status').html(x +', '+ y); 
   }); 
})
```

Which I use with this HTML code

```
<body> 
    <h2 id="status">0, 0</h2>
    <canvas style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px; border:1px ridge green;" id="canvas">

    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and trying to draw circles with radius 5 with key press.

Instead of clicking, I want a circle to appear on canvas whenever I press a key on the keyboard. Therefore, I should keep the mouse position.

I tried `mousemove`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#canvas').attr('height', $('#canvas').css('height'));
$('#canvas').attr('width', $('#canvas').css('width'));
var x = -1;
var y = -1;
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
});
$("#canvas").keypress(function(e){ 
    var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 5,0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    $('#status').html(x +', '+ y); 
});

})
```

Which did not work.

As you can guess, I am pretty new to jQuery. Therefore, I might have some syntax errors (which I believe I do not because my Chrome debugger does not show any).

My ultimate goal is to create draggable circles with keypresses. This is my first step. Can you help me?

Comment: if you check this link you can achieve it without jQuery and adding listener to canvas http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/canvas/CanvasKeyEvents.html

Comment: @JoseRojas that is good to know, thanks! but as i said, my ultimate goal is to create draggable objects. therefore, i will somehow need jquery, i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you [can't focus on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas) and without focus, it doesn't take keyboard input. Instead, setup a `keypress` listener on the `document` and check if you're over the canvas.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#canvas').attr('height', $('#canvas').css('height'));
  $('#canvas').attr('width', $('#canvas').css('width'));
  var x = -1;
  var y = -1;

  // Make sure the mouse is over the canvas
  var overCanvas = false;
  $('#canvas').mouseover(function() {
    overCanvas = true;
  });
  $('#canvas').mouseleave(function() {
    overCanvas = false;
  });
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
    // Use offset[X/Y] instead of page[X/Y]
    // page[X/Y] will only be accurate if the canvas
    // takes up the whole page
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;
  });
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (!overCanvas) {
      return;
    }
    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFF'; // Stroke in white
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    $('#status').html(x + ', ' + y);
  });

})
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
<span id="status"></span>
```