# addEventListener per element only

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make my canvas to exclusively respond to keydown/mouse EventListeners only.

Another user had this problem: [addEventListener for keydown on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas)

But the problem still persists: I have a canvas and an input box. I have the spacebar to trigger an event but when I want to type in an input element box, it will trigger as well.

How do I make keydown/mouse events exclusive for the canvas so it won't affect other elements such as my input?

```
 //js file
 gameCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32) // triggers something in canvas
 }, false); 

 //html dom
 <canvas id="gameCanvas" tabindex='1'></canvas>

 //input that accidentally triggers the above event meant for canvas
 <input type="text" id="conversation"></input>
```

Comment: Once the user has clicked into the input and typed something there, how do  you expect them to indicate that they want further typing to affect the canvas?

Comment: By clicking on either element(canvas or input), the space bar will be according to one of these. I will use the mouse to click on each element and continue with the individual space bar event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create separate keydown/click event for each of your input/canvas.

To get canvas to response to keydown you need to add `tabindex="1"`.

Like so `<canvas id="gameCanvas" tabindex="1"></canvas>`

Both input and canvas will response to keyboard event when the right elements are selected and triggered when keys are pressed. If you prefer click event just replace `keydown` with `click` instead.

```js
//js file
 gameCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
 conversation = document.getElementById('conversation');

 gameCanvas.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(gameCanvas);
 }, false); 

 conversation.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(conversation);
 }, false);
```

```css
#gameCanvas {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;   
}
```

```html
<p>gamecanvas</p>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" tabindex="1"></canvas><br />
<p>conversation</p>
 <input  id="conversation" type="text" tabindex="2"></input>
```

Comment: I've tried adding the keydown event listener to canvas but it doesn't work :(

Comment: The OP want the events from the canvas. It can not be focused and will not work.

Comment: OP's `gameCanvas` is a `<canvas>` element, not an input.

Comment: That is one way, but the focus is not easily seen, and if it is, is somewhat annoying. The expectation is to control the animation / game when no other element shows a visible focus. The default is canvas unless input elements have focus. So it is better to just have one handler that handles all keyboard input, redirecting it when needed.

Comment: @Blindman67 OP doesn't asks for this feature. He even stated [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721041#comment-80392678) that he wants to trigger focus on click. The outline can be removed with `canvas{outline: none;}` if you find it ugly. You can even react in the canvas drawing thanks to the `canvas.onfocus`/`onblur` event handlers, and if you want to implement always canvas except when other focusable has it, you can add a tabindex on your body and do `document.body.onfocus= e => setTimeout(()=>{
 if(document.activeElement===document.body)
  canvas.focus();
 }, 100)`

Comment: @Kaiido, gee wow really.. do you think i like started coding yesterday. You don't need to focus the canvas if you manage your keyboard correctly from a single event handler. All you want to do is add additional complexity for no gain at all, that is bad practice.. All he wants is to intercept the space key. One line of code is all that is needed using a single event handler.

Comment: @Blindman67 1/2, honestly?  I don't doubt of your coding capacities, but you are clearly not a web-dev, and I wouldn't ask you to write a web-page. You are too much used to fullscreen games where the only thing that matters in your page is your game. Canvas is used in many other ways, and there are a bunch of applications where adding an event-listener as you propose is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Blindman67 2/2 Take for instance any library that would allow navigation in their canvas application through keyboard, do you think the developers of this library will add on their github page *"Please edit the source code in order to add all the ids of your own elements that should handle key events (`<form>` and alikes), Oh and if you wanted to lauch two instances of this app on the same page, well, you can't."* Might not be well received...

Comment: @Kaiido, I am so over your attacks,keep your personal opinions to yourself from now on. . Writing a single handler can happily coexist with any well written library. If an app can not handle an additional event handler then it needs fixing. As for comment  2/2  none of that has any relevance. BTW the OP is writing a game incase you missed that point.

Comment: @Blindman67 you asked for it. In this case it is your code that doesn't handle multiple event listeners... event delegation is a good thing... when you can delegate the event on the real target. Here you can't.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh and what does my code do that blocks other events? you do know that the document is the last to get the event. You are in an old school mindset. Eg Ace.js (very much a keyboard driven app)  a complex multi layered multi focus UI. Yet only ONE keyboard handler, and the core of my Dev environment (plus many other libs) yet not once have I had a problem.  Maybe I will look at my Gmail page. Oh what a surprise they handle all the key events at the document, gee maybe they are also doing it all wrong like you say. Get with it man, you don't delegate hardware IO if you want to do it well.

Comment: @Blindman67 please show me where in the source code of these respectable apps they set an `if(event.target.id !== the_one_I_m_looking_for) doSomething()`. As I said event delegation is good, when you've got something to target the delegated event on. Delegating all events that are not the ones you expected to somehere  else  is simply wrong, in any school. To delegate events on a canvas element you need to make it focusable, i.e give it a tabindex. Without this, delegation will be wrong.

Comment: @Kaiido you are deliberately obtuse, read the answer.. You would write (sorry delegate) 30 listeners if you had 30 input fields with unique vetting, Oh and what fun it would be if your app had a set of context aware keyboard shortcuts, or needed to prevent some default action on some and not others. A huge mess, mostly repeating the same thing. All the extra work is worth not having to inspect the target. Knock yourself out, you must win a lot of awards and some juicy gov contracts with that approch, they must love the way you seamlessly integrate functionality for the impaired.

Comment: @Blindman67 by "delegated event" I am talking about a single event that you will listen on an ancester, like `document` which will receive all bubblings events from its descendants, before assigning the correct action to the correct descendant (event.target). It sounds like what you are proposing yourself except that in this scenario you must have a way to tell on which descendant should be delegated the event action. In your case you are doing the inverse: check if the event wasn't one of the other known targets. And you can't know if the canvas was the target unless it had the focus.

Comment: @Blindman67 And thank you for finally think about the impaireds. One of the universally accepted keyboard shortcuts on a web page is the space bar to scroll down of one page. Your code will act against this universal feature. (And btw, gov is ok with my work for now, thanks for asking).

Answer (score -1):

### Canvas can not be focused

Keyboard events can be listened to by element if the element has focus. This can be a little problematic as the canvas will not take the focus and thus can not listen to keyboard events.

Your best bet is to use the document keyboard events and redirect the call depending on the current document focus or the target of the event.

```
function canvasKeyHandler(event) {
    // handle the key event 

}
document.addEventListener("keydown",(event) => {
    if(event.target.id !== "conversation"){ // redirect to canvas
        canvasKeyHandler(event);
    }else{
        // handle the key event for the input
    }
})
```

You can also check which element has the focus with `document.activeElement` which returns the active (focused) element.

Comment: Would it work to test if the `event.target` was `document`?

Comment: @nnnnnn could do, I have never tested for document focus. All the test has to do is ensure only elements that need handling get the event, all else should then pass to the canvas handling function. The users expectation for keyboard input is to the canvas (if game or animation) is when no other visible focus is apparent.