# Why image drawn by putImageData seems brighter than the original created by drawImage?

Tags: html5-canvas

As titled, I created an image via drawImage. Then I get it back via getImageData and the paste it back by putImage data. But the copied one is brighter. Code as follows:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,1190,595);
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,595);
```

Comment: Why do you say its brighter. If what you say is true then doing i = 200; while(i--){ ctx.putImageData(ctx.getImageData(0,0,1190,595),0,0)} should make it lot brighter, no? Using getImageData and putImageData will not change  the pixels. If it does then there is a problem with your hardware, browser, or setup as it should not change pixels.

Comment: What browser? (OS and version). Can you link to an example image you experienced this issue with?

Comment: @Kaiido As usual you are wrong .The spec says getting after putting may return different values due to Alpha premultiplication. However if you are getting, you are getting already premultiplied pixels, they will not find another premultiplied value after you put them back. The spec does not say alpha pre multiplication is  nondeterministic .

Comment: @Blindman67 *"As usual"*? Let me laugh, can you point me where I was wrong while talking with you? Are you referring to [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/184503/2018/11/30) for instance? You were completely wrong, [as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721041/addeventlistener-per-element-only/46721666#46721666). And here, I may have misread your comment, and I am sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, I am not sure what's I have seen, but this is likely a hardware issue. With the same image, if I copy and paste it vertically. I can certainly see that the copied one (i.e., the lower one) is brighter, as I can see more detail in it. However, if I do it horizontally, both of them appear to be the same. The most interesting thing is that, for the vertical one, if I scroll up a bit and look at the originally brighter one at the same level of the originally dimmer one, the detail lost and looks like the dimmer one now. Tried this on 2 different brand of monitors and got the same result.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].