# "react-hot-loader/babel" breaks my build -- why is it needed?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

As soon as I add `"react-hot-loader/babel"` to my `.babelrc`, it breaks my React components.

Specifically, I have some code that looks like this:

```
export default class Editor extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this.canvas',this.canvas);
        // ...
    }

    setRef = node => {
        console.log('setRef');
        this.canvas = node;
    }

    render() {
        // tabIndex is needed to receive keyboard events -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887221/65387
        return <canvas className={this.props.className} ref={this.setRef} tabIndex={0} />;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I see this in my Chrome dev tools:

> setRef
>   this.canvas undefined

Which is quite strange, because we can see it's setting `this.canvas` *before* calling `componentDidMount` so I don't know what `react-hot-loader/babel` is doing to break that.

Without `react-hot-loader/babel`, everything works fine, including hot-reloading.

So, my questions are:

1. What does "react-hot-loader/babel" actually do?
2. How do I get it to *not* break my class properties?

---

This is with React 16.1, react-hot-loader 3, webpack 3.11, babel 6.x

---

My `.babelrc` if you want to see that:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "syntax-jsx",
        "transform-react-jsx",
        "transform-react-display-name",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-function-bind",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],
    "compact": false,
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": [
                "transform-react-jsx-self",
                "transform-react-jsx-source",
                [
                    "styled-components",
                    {
                        "displayName": true,
                        "minify": false
                    }
                ]
                // https://stackoverflow.com/q/48857689/65387
                //"react-hot-loader/babel"
            ],
            "presets": [
                [
                    "env",
                    {
                        "targets": {
                            "browsers": "last 2 chrome versions"
                        },
                        "modules": false
                    }
                ]
            ],
        },
        "webpack": {
            "presets": [
                [
                    "env",
                    {
                        "targets": {
                            "node": "current"
                        },
                        "modules": "commonjs"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some this binding issue?

Comment: I checked your code in a fresh installation of create-react-app and it works with ES7 proposals, so my guess goes towards your webpack configuration is missing any directive when adding `react-hot-loader`.

Comment: @Dez Thanks Dez. What directive might I be missing? Here's my webpack file: https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/df723cb33682c137290caefaf890444e

Comment: @mpen, can you create a minimal project with issue? Would help resolve your issue much faster

Comment: @TarunLalwani Here: https://transfer.sh/9i0du/stack48857689.zip Run `yarn` and then `yarn dev` to start it (or `npm i` and `npm run dev` if you prefer)

Comment: @mpen, this works for me, as such. What issue do you get?

Comment: @mpen which version of react-hot-loader are you using ? (Can you share your `package.json` react-hot-loader version i.e: `"react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6"`)

Comment: @Aaqib It's in the yarn.lock file I posted: 3.1.3

Comment: @TarunLalwani Did you look at the console? https://i.imgur.com/heSN6DR.png componentDidMount gets `undefined`. It shouldn't be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/537) in react-hot-loader v3 (I was able to reproduce the issue) and it is [fixed](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/537#issuecomment-353870549) in react-hot-loader v4.

As per [this comment](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/537#issuecomment-302903789), this issue seems to be caused by the proxying logic in react-proxy. One trick is to store an object to hold your references, this will get copied to the proxy by react-proxy and will be available in the proxy version of `this`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRefs = {};
        this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount',this.myRefs.div); // <-- Not null!
    }

    setRef(node) {
        this.myRefs.div = node;
        console.log('setRef',this.myRefs.div);
    };

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.setRef}>test</div>
    }
}
```

Or as mentioned in the [next comment](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/537#issuecomment-302908659), make sure your function bindings are done in `componentWillMount`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Do not bind here, "this" will get proxied.
    }

    // Proxy "this" is now available. Bind here.
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount',this.div); // <-- Not null!
    }

    setRef(node) {
        this.div = node;
        console.log('setRef',this.div);
    };

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.setRef}>test</div>
    }
}
```

I did verify the code in question with react-hot-loader [v4](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/next) and it is fixed there.

Comment: Yup. That looks like the bug, and a workaround. You get the points (thank you). I do wish someone would answer the other half my question though. What the heck is `react-hot-loader/babel` supposed to do aside from wreck havoc? Because HMR works with or without it.

Comment: `react-hot-loader` is for preserving internal component state. HMR will work without it; but component state will be lost after each reload. You might want to read this post by Dan Abramov to know what's going on under the hood - https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/hot-reloading-in-react-1140438583bf.

Answer (score 1):

PS: Using answer as comments as I need formatting

I was able to reproduce the issue. The issue occurs because hot reloader changes the code to

```
setRef = (...params) => this.__setRef__REACT_HOT_LOADER__(...params)
```

And then in the `prototype` of the component

```
__setRef__REACT_HOT_LOADER__(node) {
        console.log("setRef called", this, node);
        if (this === null) return;
        if (node === null) return;
        console.log(node);
        this.div = node;
    }
```

This I believe breaks the `this` chain or this copies get different. There are two changes where it will work

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('componentDidMount',this.div);
}
```

If you use the above then it would work, because of get same this then. Or you need to change the setRef to a lambda

```
return <div ref={ node => this.div=node }>test</div>
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for explaining what's going on here.