# keydown event is not being detected

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, 2d-games

I am quite new to JavaScript and I am making a small game on it as a project. I am trying to detect 'keydown' event but it is not working for some reason. I have been on this for hours but I cant figure it out.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                 
c.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

function keyDown(e){
   console.log(e.key);
}
```

I have already tried the 'keypress' event, but that didn't work either. I have tried 2 mouse events and they are working perfectly so the problem is just with the keyboard events.

Comment: Sounds like a focus issue on a canvas. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886286/addeventlistener-for-keydown-on-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen window events, try this:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

function keyDown(e){
    console.log(e.key);
}
```

To listen document events, this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

function keyDown(e){
    console.log(e.key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. I dont understand why using c.addEventListener didnt work. I was also using c.addEventListener("click", function(e){  in my code for detecting mouseclicks. and that is working perfectly fine

Comment: it's about focus the key events

Comment: The issue is that the focus isn't on the canvas element, so it isn't receiving the keydown event. This solution puts the event listener on the document which receives all of its children elements' events if they bubble up.

Comment: oh i understand now thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

The element to which you are adding the key events must be focused for the events to actually occur. In case it's a div, it would need a explicit tabindex to get focused via tab keys and then key events for which you added listeners to it would work